# Bluetooth not working on MacBook Pro Early '15 with Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: bluetooth, macbook

I installed Ubuntu 19.10 on this Mac a couple of weeks ago. Bluetooth used to work the first days, but now the bluetooth device is not found anymore:

```
> hcitool dev
Devices:
```

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [14e4:43ba] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [106b:0133]
    Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac
    Kernel modules: brcmfmac
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05ac:8406 Apple, Inc. Card Reader
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05ac:0273 Apple, Inc. Internal Keyboard/Trackpad (ISO)
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05ac:8290 Apple, Inc. Bluetooth Host Controller
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 046d:081b Logitech, Inc. Webcam C310
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1038:1202 SteelSeries ApS Gaming Mouse G502
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c332 Logitech, Inc. G502 Proteus Spectrum Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of `dmesg | grep -i blue`:

```
[    1.562871] usb 1-3: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[    2.104835] input: Broadcom Corp. Bluetooth USB Host Controller as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:05AC:8290.0003/input/input10
[    2.164582] hid-generic 0003:05AC:8290.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Broadcom Corp. Bluetooth USB Host Controller] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input0
[    2.164685] input: Broadcom Corp. Bluetooth USB Host Controller as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.1/0003:05AC:8290.0004/input/input11
[    2.164761] hid-generic 0003:05AC:8290.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Broadcom Corp. Bluetooth USB Host Controller] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input1
[    3.605086] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.605103] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.605107] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.605109] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.605112] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.720427] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c03 tx timeout
[    6.637120] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.637122] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.637126] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   13.876494] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reset failed (-110)
```

Comment: Please add output of `dmesg | grep -i blue`

Comment: @Pilot6 going to add it

Comment: `hci0: command 0x0c03 tx timeout` this is a sort of a bug, that can be reported by `ubuntu-bug linux`.

Comment: I filed a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1861295

Comment: Meanwile try to boot with a previous 5.0 kernel using grub menu. A good chance that BT will work.

Comment: @Pilot6 OMG you're right, with 5.3.0-18-generic bluetooth works while with 5.3.0-29-generic it doesn't... how it could be that such a minor version introduces a regression like this? Or is there another explanation?

Comment: I think there is no other explanation, but some kernel regression with backportuing something to Ubuntu kernels.

Comment: @Pilot6 thank you so much, you saved my day! gonna lock the kernel image!

Comment: Add this information to the bug report.

Comment: Even more weird: I rebooted on the newer kernel (5.3.0-29-generic) and now it works even here... could it be that the old kernel unlocked something at firmware level? I'll try to hybernate the PC and see if it affects the Bluetooth behaviour, I remember I hybernated the pc some days ago

Comment: This happens. The old kernel loaded firmware, the new one failed, but the firmware had been loaded already. BT works.